# Why isnt my jquery AJAX function firing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

on my main html page i have an empty Div

```
 <div id="accordion" >

 </div>
```

at the end of the html file i linked a script.js file, which contains the following jquery AJAX function

```
    $(function() {

    var $accordion= $("#accordion");

    $.ajax({

    type:'GET',
    url: "PDOconnect.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i,data){

    $accordion.append('<p>'+ data.name + '</p>');


     })
     },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    }
    });// end ajax 
    });
```

which is connected to a PDO database query that JSON encodes all the data in the DB

```
    if($dbh)
    {

    $sql="SELECT * FROM 
      IFC JOIN tables ON IFC.tablename = tables.id AND IFC.location =       :location
      ORDER BY Numopinions, votes DESC 
      ";
     $stmt= $dbh->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(":location", $location);
     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     if($stmt->execute())
         {
             $rows = $stmt-> fetchAll();
             echo json_encode($rows);
         }
      }

     $dbh= null;
```

is it possible that the function isnt firing because my js file also uses the DOM in the function?

```
      $(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
      });
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Anything being returned?

Comment: alright its giving me a parse error

Comment: So that means the response back from the server is not valid JSON. Look at the response in the developer tools and see what is being returned.

Comment: thank you so much, the error was in the PHP file, it was appending a comment i made in the file to the  JSON encoded response.